# Google login oauth integration doesn't work in Windows PWA app

Tags: windows, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, progressive-web-apps, google-signin

I have developed a PWA application with google and microsoft oauth login integration.Now I want the PWA application to run as windows PWA app in windows mobile and desktop applications, so I tried registering the app using AppX as stated in the following link, https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/02/06/welcoming-progressive-web-apps-edge-windows-10/#R6xvoOyZeLza5oGW.97
and ran the application in development mode using PowerShell in windows 10 OS version, the microsoft login works great, However when I try to login using google the application starts loading and exits after some time.[the popup to show the login window also doesn't come up].

Could anyone throw a light on what's happening ?.I researched but I couldn't get any solutions.

**Edit**
The following API is used for login with google, in the client[react]

```js
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: constant.CLIENT_ID,
        cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: constant.SCOPE,
      });
    });
```

```js
loginWithGoogle = () => {
    const options = {
      scope: constant.SCOPE,
    };
    options.prompt = 'select_account';
    this.provider = 'google';
    this.auth2.grantOfflineAccess(options).then((data) => {
      this.loginUser(data.code);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include enough code to recreate the issue.

Comment: @DalmTo I have added the code that initializes the gapi for oauth login

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because your browser´s popup blocker, anyway you could use redirection instead popup mode, using ux_mode option (you have to configure the redirection url on OAuth 2.0 client IDs options)

```
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        ux_mode: 'redirect', 
        client_id: constant.CLIENT_ID,
        cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: constant.SCOPE,
      });
    });
```